# Configuring database development environment along with Hibernate and Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, liquibase

We have a web-based application in dev phase where we use Spring 5, JPA(Hibernate) and Postgresql 9.4

Till this moment we were using one instance of the posgresql db for our work. Basically, we don't have any schema generation script and we simply were updating the db if we needed some new table, column etc. For the Hibernate we were generating classes from the db.

Now when we have some amount of test data and each change in the db brings a lot of trouble and confusion. We realized that we need to create and start maintaining some schema generation file along with some scripts which generate test data.

After some research, we see two options

1. Create two *.sql files. The first will contain the schema generation script the second one SQL to create test data. Then add a small module with a class which will execute the *.sql files using plain jdbc. Basically, we will continue developing and whenever we made some changes we quickly wipe->create->populate the db. This approach looks the most appealing to us at this point. It quick, simple, robust.
2. Second is to set up some tool which may help with that e.g. [Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/)
   This approach also looks good in terms of versioning support and other capabilities. However, we are not in production yet, we are in an active development phase. We don't have much of the devs who do the db changes and we are not sure how frequently we will update the db schema in production, it could be rare.

The question is the following. Would the first approach be a bad practice and applying the second one will give the most benefits and it worth to use it?

Would appreciate any comments or any other suggestions!

Comment: Since (as you said) you  are in early development phase, why don't you just let hibernate generate your schema for you? This is the simplest solution. It is actually "a bad practice" production-wise, since any decent DBA will tell you that the hibernate autogenerated schema is far from perfect (regarding column order among others), but for test purposes this is very simple and easy to maintain (no maintnance whatsoever needed). The same can be done with test data, just add a @Before method (if you are using JUnit) that loads the data using JPA daos

Comment: @JanOssowski Thanks. However, we would need to change it somewhere in future and we are looking for some approach which potentially will allow us to go to production without change. Anyway, we set up Liquibase and I believe that is a good choice in most cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest second approach as it will automatically find the new script as you add and execute the script on startup. Moreover, when you have tools available like `liquibase` and `flyway` why reinvent the wheel ?.

2nd approach will also reduce the un-necessary code for manually executing the *.sql files. Moreover this code also needs testing and if updated can be error prone.

Moreover 1st approach where you write manual code to execute script also has to check which scripts needs to be executed.. If you already has existing database and you are adding some new scripts you need to execute those new scripts only. These things are taken care of automatically with 2nd approach and you don't need to worry about already executed script being executed again

Hope this answers your concern. Happy coding

Comment: Thanks @Hiren. I think you answered our question with good arguments. We set up the Liquibase and now starting to see some benefits in terms of convenience and I'm sure we will see more down the road.

Answer (score 1):

First approach is NOT a bad practice, until this generation. But it will be considering the growth of tools like Liquibase.

If you are in the early or middle of the Development Phase, go ahead with LiquiBase, along with Spring Data. Contrarily, in the closing stages of the Development Phase, Think you real need for it.

Comment: Thanks for giving an exact answer regarding the bad practice. After some discussion, we decided to go with 2 approach and use Liquibase.